# Bootstrap columns moving to the left when responsive

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I tried to upload and image, but for some reason it wasn't working.

Basically, I have a long list of hyperlinks in `div class="col-md-4"`, so there is three columns. On PC and Laptop it looks absolutely fine, but when responsive using mobiles, all the links go right to the lefthand of the screen.

How do I make them central when responsive?

Thanks for your time

Comment: Show your code please

Comment: There are 3 classes with `col-md-4` for the screen medium, `col-lg-4` for the large screen and in your case for the mobile `col-xs-4` for the small screen. You must add the class corresponding to the screen size of a mobile.

Comment: @FoxCy, so in my case - does that mean it would be div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4" as I want one column on mobile... but 3 on desktop?

Comment: @Matt1966 You got it ;). More seriously, you always have to put 2 on the 3 classes to be webresponsive. Bootstrap help you to do it but you must specify what you want ^^

Comment: @FoxCy, thank you very much!

Comment: @Matt1966 You're welcome, it's nice to help ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer this code:

```html
<!-- Stack the columns on mobile by making one full-width and the other half-width -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">.col-xs-12 .col-md-8</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
</div>

<!-- Columns start at 50% wide on mobile and bump up to 33.3% wide on desktop -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
</div>

<!-- Columns are always 50% wide, on mobile and desktop -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">.col-xs-6</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">.col-xs-6</div>
</div>
```